# Why is SCL-AKL slower than SYD-SCL?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

How is it that the estimated duration of a SYD-SCL flight (7060 miles) on a 747-400 (cruise speed Mach 0.85) is 12:40, but SCL-AKL flight (6011 miles) on a 787-8 (same cruise speed) takes 13:20.

My first thought was perhaps wind direction. So I ran a quick calculation assuming SYD-SCL always has a 10m/s tail wind, and SCL-AKL has a 10m/s head wind. The numbers come out as:

```
7060 miles / (252.1m/s + 10m/s) = 12:02
6011 miles / (252.1m/s - 10m/s) = 11:06
```

So it's probably not wind, so why does it take longer for a 1000 mile shorter flight?

Comment: Argh, super powers in [tag:air-travel].  I think it's a dupe in that the answer is the same - the drag of the spin of the earth, instead of flying with the drag, you're flying against it. If you don't think it's a dupe, feel free to vote to reopen.

Comment: Also see [Does flying east to west generally take longer than west to east in America?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5853/does-flying-east-to-west-generally-take-longer-than-west-to-east-in-america)

Comment: Ah so my issue is grossly under approximating the wind speed.

Comment: And when you say "drag of spin", you mean the prevailing wind yes?

Comment: Basically, yes. The air is dragged with the earth, My [answer here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5601/does-the-rotation-of-the-earth-affect-the-travel-time-from-europe-to-australia) has a quote describing it better than I can :)

Comment: Answers given here and in the other question tend to hide the true answer in interesting essentially irrelevant complexities. The answer is essentially "Differences in wind speed and direction at cruise altitude on each route." Some of this is caused by earth's rotation affects but that is secondary to the main observed effect.

Comment: This question was closed too early.