# Why are flights departing Athens shorter than their returns at night?

Tags: air-travel

My flight from Athens to Corfu lasted 1 hour and 10 minutes (left at 14:55). My return flight with the same airline (Ryanair) and same type of plane lasted about 45 minutes (left at 21:10).

Same thing with flight from Athens to Mytilini airport  (50 minutes (morning) while return flight (night) was 35 minutes. Unfortunately I cannot remember flight details such as departure times and airline).

I generally see this happening in domestic flights in Greece.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Scheduled time or actual time?

Comment: It's possible taxiing, queuing and leaving Athens takes longer because it's a bigger, busier airport.

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5602/3221 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5853/3221

Comment: @JonathanReez Editing the question for the details of the flight

Comment: How are you measuring the time?  Gate to gate?  Takeoff to landing?  Something else?

Comment: @phoog After every takeoff the pilot announces the estimated time of flight. It is different in each occasion

Comment: @papakias estimated total time of flight, or estimated time remaining in the flight?

Comment: @pnuts I went to Corfu on Friday and returned on Wednesday

Comment: @pnuts or they could be pushback to landing, which seems to be what US airlines use (when they land, they usually tout their "early arrival" even though you may be stuck on the plane for another 20 or 30 minutes).

Comment: @phoog I think it is total time of flight because the departure time was 14:55 and we arrived at 16:05 (1 hour and ten minutes after). On our flight back departure time was 21:10 and we arrived at 21:55

Comment: @papakias meaning total time in the air?  But the plane doesn't typically push back from the gate until the departure time, so if your departure time was 2:55 you didn't take off until at least 10 minutes after that.  And when you say "arrive" do you mean that the plane's wheels touched the runway then, or you arrived at the destination gate then?

Comment: The flights are you talking about are [RYR6596](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/RYR6596/history) and possibly [RYR6597](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/RYR6597/history) for the return.

Comment: @everybody I know that my question is not very specific. I just noticed that this happens when return flight is at night and I was wondering if there is any reason for that happening. I cannot remember details though. I only take under consideration the time told by the pilot at his announcement right after takeoff.

Answer (score 3):

The question is really not specific enough for us to answer with any precision.  There are many factors that can affect the duration of a flight, and we don't even know exactly which parts of the flight are included in the timings you cite.  I will assume that they are from your departure gate to your arrival gate.

The most likely explanation seems to be that when you leave Athens your plane is generally waiting behind a line of several other planes before it can take off, and when flying to Athens this does not happen.  Another possible factor is that one of the runways at Athens is much closer to the terminal than the other.  If your outbound flight used the farther runway, and your inbound flight did not, that would contribute to the difference in time.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot be more specific. I noticed that this difference exists when return flight is at night.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is the air-borne time, then, it could be because of the [jet stream](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiKpc7vm7bPAhUFkpQKHZdnDe0QFggkMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FJet_stream&authuser=1&usg=AFQjCNEW-GIJnzEyCpPW0wD2o3SOVBetIQ&sig2=hvmMry-NxNbwS1hl-AjZsQ&bvm=bv.134495766,d.dGo), plus Corfu to Athens is West to East.

Comment: Do such short flights even have time to climb to an altitude where the jet stream matters?